# Is this possible in p tag without using span or anything new in html tag?

Tags: html, css

I want paragraph text should look like this can anyone help to achieve this in p tag without using any other span or html tag. First line is big and other line is small ?

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
```

Comment: wants each line to wrap at smaller lengths, without using `<br>` `<span>` etc - i don't think this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this - p {white-space:pre;}

Answer (score 6):

I think you want the [`:first-line` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-line-pseudo).

```
p:first-line { font-size: 150%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `white-space:pre;`

**pre**

*This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.*

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space)

---

```
p {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c5xN9/1/)

To add a bigger font-size to the first line use  `p:first-line`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Mt4/)

[:first-line](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3afirst-line)

```
selector::first-line{ preperties }
```